# Coinbase deposit PLZ HELP

Tags: security, coinbase

I deposited $ into Coinbase from my bank account, however the money hasn't cleared yet and it will only be available in 7 days. Do I get the price of ETH BTC LTC when I clicked 'BUY' (although it hasn't cleared) or when the money is in my Coinbase account?

Comment: Hi there. This is a question about a 3rd-party application, which is considered off-topic for this site. You'll need to contact them directly to know what their policy is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You get your currency for the price that it was when you bought it.